# Django multilanguage support

Tags: django, django-models, internationalization, django-views, django-settings

Using django if a text is stored in French  or Hindi.How will this be stored and retrieved in a text box field

Models.py

```
    class Details(models.Model):
         title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

html page:

```
  <form action="/pjt/details">
  <input type="text" name="nee_n"id="neen_n" />
   </form>
```

How to store this in the db and retieve back the same .Is there any setting to be changed in settings.py

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Django is based on Unicode and so the language characters will be stored correctly.

Storing the language, i.e. the user's culture is a different issue. This can be initially gleaned from the HTTP request in the format 'en_US' or 'fr_FR'.

This standard is a concatenation of ISO 639-1 and ISO 3166-1.

However the browser culture cannot always be relied upon and so the interface should give the user the opportuinity to change their culture.